# ¿Cómo esperar a que un ciclo con llamadas ajax termine sin que el codigo siga ejecutándose?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, bucles

Me gustaria esperar a que un ciclo que contiene llamadas ajax termine, pero el codigo sigue ejecutandose sin importar que el ciclo haya terminado, es posible esperar a que termine el proceso?

```
$('#adjuntar-archivos').on('click',function(){
        console.log("se van a enviar los archivos al servidor");
        var promises = [];
        $("input[type='file']").each(function (index, value) {
            var el = $(this)[0];
            console.log("enviando archivo: "+el);
            var request = saveFile(el);
            promises.push(request);
        });
       
        $.when.apply(null,promises).done(function(){
            console.log("todos subidos");
           //aca quiero continuar haciendo cosas pero luego de que termine todas las llamadas al servidor
        });
        
    });
```

Agrego aqui abajo el metodo saveFile() que es el que contiene el ajax.

```
function saveFile(inputFile) {
        var data = new FormData()
        var input = $(inputFile);
        var inputId = input.attr("data-id");
        data.append("file", inputFile.files[0]);
        data.append("idAdjunto", input.attr("data-id"));

        var label = input.siblings("label");
        var url = "/Solicitud/ActualizarAdjunto";
        var miInit = {
            url: url,
            method: 'POST',
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
        };

        var buttonEdit = input.parents(".file-action");
        var spinner = buttonEdit.siblings(".spinner");

        buttonEdit.hide();
        spinner.show();


        $.ajax(miInit)
            .done(function(json) {
                buttonEdit.show();
                spinner.hide();
                if (json.code != 200) {
                    showMessage(json.message, "danger");
                    logearExcepcion(fileSize);
                }

                if (json.code == 200) {

                }
            }).error(function(error){
                spinner.hide();
                buttonEdit.show();
                showMessage("Archivo no adjuntado. Favor vuelva a intentarlo.", "danger");
                logearExcepcion(fileSize);
            });
    }
```

He agregado un array promises[] cuando estaba buscando una solucion, pero cuando tengo muchos adjuntos, esta solucion no funciona, seria la sgte parte:

```
        $.when.apply(null,promises).done(function(){
            console.log("todos subidos");
            window.location.reload();
        });
```

Comment: Te recomiendo replantear tu lógica, porque la idea de usar AJAX es, precisamente, que el usuario pueda realizar acciones sin tener que recargar la página.

Comment: Tienes razon, la he modificado, en realidad mi curiosidad va mas por saber como detener la ejecucion del codigo y esperar a que las llamadas ajax terminen completamente. He leido sobre llamadas sincronas, pero no logro hacer que funcione.

Comment: No estás devolviendo una promesa, tal vez sea suficiente `return $.ajax(miInit)`